# How to hide the full row if any cell value is null in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, pipe, httpclient

I would like to hide the row for the while payment due date cell is empty for the respective row.
while any value of Payment Due Date is null or empty I would like to hide the whole row respectively.
[image]

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {

  constructor( private http:HttpClient) { }

  getData(){
    let url="https://Test.azurewebsites.net/api/accounts/getall";
    return this.http.get(url);

  } 
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { analyzeAndValidateNgModules } from '@angular/compiler';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersService} from './users.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'coding-test';
  data : any
  constructor( private user:UsersService){
    this.user.getData().subscribe(data=>{
      console.warn(data)
      this.data = data
    })
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-6">Display Sorted Account Info</h1>
    <table class="table table-striped" >
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Phone</th>
              <th >Amount Due</th>
              <th>Payment Due Date</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of data"  >
              <td>{{item.LastName}},{{item.FirstName}}</td>
              <td>{{item.Email}}</td>
              <td>{{item.PhoneNumber | phone}}</td>
              <td>{{item.AmountDue | currency}}</td>
              <td>{{item.PaymentDueDate | date}}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on `app.component.ts` you can add **filter** by **changing** ((`this.data = data` )) to :

```
this.data = data.filter(x=>x.PaymentDueDate !== null );
```

Comment: got this error. Any idea how to solve this
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:22:24 - error TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'.

22       this.data = data.filter((x: { PaymentDueDate: null; })=>x.PaymentDueDate !== null );

Comment: just fixed it. thanks.used this line of code
if(Array.isArray(data)){
        this.data = data.filter(
                     res => res.PaymentDueDate   !== null);
     }

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter out the object based on the condition in your ts file.This will solve your problem.

Comment: do i need to do it on user.service.ts or app.component.ts?

Comment: Its your wish although in service layer it would be better.